# Error occurs while using SPADE method in R

Tags: r, data-mining

I'm currently mining sequence patterns using SPADE algorithm in R.
SPADE is included in `arulesSequence` package of R.
I'm running R on my CentOS 6.3 64bit.

For an exercise,
I've tried an example presented in http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Sequence_Mining/SPADE

When I tried to do

```
cspade(x, parameter = list(support = 0.4), control = list(verbose = TRUE))
```

R says:

```
parameter specification:    
support : 0.4
maxsize :  10
maxlen  :  10

algorithmic control:     
bfstype : FALSE     
verbose :  TRUE
summary : FALSE

preprocessing ... 1 partition(s), 0 MB [0.096s]     
mining transactions ... 0 MB [0.066s]    
reading sequences ...Error in asMethod(object) : 's' is not an integer vector
```

When I try to run SPADE on my Window 7 32bit,
it runs well without any error.

Does anybody know why such errors occur?

Comment: "x" contains the result of 
"x <- read_baskets(con = system.file("misc", "zaki.txt", package = "arulesSequences"), info = c("sequenceID","eventID","SIZE"))". zaki.txt is in the example of arulesSequences package.